# How long would it take before the water flowing out from an encased and flooded suburb is drinkable?

Tags: survival, water

One of the early events in my story involves a 2x2 mile section of a suburban town that is encased in invisible walls 100 feet (30m) high and perpetually subjected to heavy rain at a rate of about an inch an hour. It will keep filling up with water until it goes over the 100 foot (30m) walls roughly 50 days later, and from then on it will become a massive four-directional waterfall that, I suspect, will start carving massive rivers and radically altering the landscape. The specifics of what that would look like are a question for another day, however. Right now what I want to know is when, if ever, the water flowing out of that flooded suburb will be drinkable.

Given that nearly the entire planet has been subjected to frequently-dangerous supernatural ordeals like this one, modern society has entirely collapsed, and smaller communities need to figure out how to survive without things like advanced plumbing infrastructure. Living near such a huge source of water would be an incredibly valuable asset... if it were drinkable. [But when I asked questions about how quickly said suburban deathtrap would start flooding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/200254/how-quickly-would-an-inch-per-hour-of-rain-flood-an-enclosed-2x2-mile-area), several people brought up something that had completely slipped my mind: the sheer amount of pollution that would get into that flood water due to the suburb it's built on and render it completely undrinkable.

**If a 2x2 mile section of a modern American suburb were encased in 100ft (30m) high walls and flooded, how long would it take before the water flowing out over those walls would no longer be too contaminated and polluted to drink?**

Comment: How long under which conditions?

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica Do I not have enough details in the OP? What's missing?

Comment: The time needed for the polluting load to be neutralized depends on the conditions in which the water is kept. On those conditions you are saying nothing

Comment: You mean how clean the rain constantly filling it is? It so, completely clean.

Comment: What's your standard for potability? There are very few existing natural sources of water that meet most (first world) government standards for potability. For that matter, some *municipal* water supplies don't meet some of the stricter standards for potability. Also, are we assuming the rain is pure H₂0, or...?

Comment: @Matthew Yes, pure H2O.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Not as much pollution as you think

The reservoir is filling so quickly, draining from the top, and the area exposed to the suburbs is so small relative to the volume that it just cannot contaminate it quickly enough to matter at the top of the water column. The "box" is acting like a giant settling tank, so very few particles will even make it to the top.

If you boil the water it will be completely drinkable. Even without boiling the water will be safe by most survival standards. There is just too much water compared to the amount of contaminants. Remember, we have reservoirs that literally contain flooded towns. Only in the very beginning when there is a lot of sediment and contaminants relative to the amount of water will it be dangerous.

You are looking at 300,000,000 cubic meters of water. That is more than most reservoirs hold. For scale, NY's largest reservoir, New Croton Reservoir, hold 70,000,000 cubic meters. All of the reservoirs in NY state's combined only hold 2,000,000,000 cubic meters of water. 4 square miles of suburbs just cannot supply enough contaminants in a few weeks of being submersed in essentially still water.

Keep in mind this is a survival situation. Minor impurities that may have long terms effects in 40 years are irrelevant. A suburb just cannot supply enough chemical contaminants in such a short time scale, so you only have to worry about biological contaminants, hence boiling. Even without boiling the risks involved are small, the influx of fresh water is just too fast. Would I want to drink it today? Not for long. Would I drink it in a post apocalyptic/survival setting? Absolutely.

Once you settle into rebuilding a civilization and years start going by, you may want to start actually purifying it, because things inside will start failing and breaking down, but even then the water coming out of your box will be cleaner than most reservoirs. The refresh rate on the water is outstanding, and the shape minimizes the migration of contaminants. Your water is clean by most pre-industrial standards and tolerable by modern ones.

Eventually the contaminants from the suburbs will be exhausted and in a few hundred years you have the cleanest water on the planet. Again many real reservoirs contains submerged towns. Monument City, Indiana was filled in 1965 submerging an entire town. NY contains dozens of flooded towns in its reservoirs, Ashokan Reservoir alone contains at least four towns flooded in their entirety. Keep in mind water in real reservoirs is flowing because it is coming in from rivers not magic rain so it is also far better at destroying and thus exposing stuff in the towns.

Comment: So, my city is wasting a lot of  money into maintaining a whole set of purification plants while they could simply boil off the water they feed in the city pipes?

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica If the city had a fresh water reservoir of this scale filled this quickly absolutely. Of course boiling that much water uses way more energy than normal purification which is Why cities don't use it. Keep in mind there is a big difference between legally potable and drinkable in a survival setting.

Comment: @john Your last number suggests you don't know that a cubic meter is 1000 liters...

Comment: @ZeissIkon thansk for catching that, got lazy and tried to use google

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica Note that boiling water takes a lot of energy. It might be that the purification plant they have is more energy efficient and hence (in the long term) cheaper than 'simply boiling'.

Comment: Boiling water is nice to kill germs, but does not do much for your chemical contaminants (the gasoline in cars and the kitchen cleaners, paint removers, medicine, etc)

Comment: @john About NY's reservoirs: 550 billion gallons is 2 billion cubic metres, not 2 million. 2 million cubic metres is 'only' 800 swimming pools. NY's reservoirs hold roughly 6.5 supernaturally flooded suburbs. Storing 250-ish litres of water for each inhabitant of NY wouldn't last long when an average person uses hundreds of litres a day.

Comment: @Inductiveload good catch, I'll fix that.

Comment: @D.J.Klomp there just is not much of those compared to the volume of water, and most of them are in containers that will we slow to leak. The sad truth is we already pump a lot of those things in our drinking water. Again I am not comparing it to modern clean water standards but to historic ones, because this is closer to a post apaocolypic setting.

Answer (score 17):

**That which can float, will soon float to the sides** and eventually go over the waterfall.
(your barrier is spilling 20.43 cubic meters of water per hour, per meterlength of outside wall.)
And yes, even at a mere 2x2 miles it will be subject to a bit of tides, a lot of wind-driven waves, and will slosh over the sides instead of just gently dribbling.
Note that this will include most of the noxious chemicals we use, such as oil, gasoline, etc.

**That which wants to sink, will sink** and settle on the bottom.

The only problem will be **anything that dissolves in the water**, either once-off or via continuous contamination (like **rotting organics**)
And *these* will be continuously diluted by the influx of pure water.

I expect that the water will be fine as soon as all the organics have finished rotting, so give it maybe 6 months. This will also allow any rapid pollutant releases to deplete themselves. For example, gas tank of automobiles.

But for many, many years the water will have a slight sheen of oil on it, as the many machines and devices and storage tanks and containers rust through and gradually release their oily residue. The water will not be *undrinkable*, but it will not be a fresh mountain stream!

---

later comment:
Remember that we are looking at a 100ft deep container, completely full, with rainwater falling on top at a rate that would have filled the container in 50 days. If using full mixing and only dilution to get rid of pollutants, we would only be halving the concentration every 25 days.
But because both the inlet (rainfall) and outlet(spillage over the edges) occurs at the very top of this reservoir, and there is no force *at all* to cause internal turnover currents, there will be *very little* mixing of the water. Mostly what will go over the edge is newly fallen rainwater, and anything that floats in the water.
Dissolved contamination, even without any source of replenishment, will dilute at a rate of something *less* (possibly much less) than halving every 25 days.

Comment: Rusting through a tank enough to produce a visible slick takes decades, starting from a serviceable container.  Oil in crankcases and such will wash out early; they aren't sealed.  And suburbs rarely have above-ground storage for large amounts of hydrocarbons -- underground storage will last longer than that, because it's required to be very resistant to corrosion.

Comment: @ZeissIkon a 2x2mile of suburbia will typically include 6 to 10 gas stations, each storing many thousands of gallons, plus approximately 12000 automobiles (if american suburbia. 1/3rd that in europe) , most of them with half-full fuel tanks.

Comment: @ZeissIkon as for leaking. virtually *NO* hydrocarbon liquid storage is airtight. For the simple reason of thermal expansion, almost all containers and absolutely al large storage tanks include air venting. They rely on gravity to keep the liquids inside. Thus slow leakage is inevitable.

Comment: I ran the tidal flux for the last question I got an amplitude of 1mm, so it does not matter much.

Comment: @PcMan You might also want to run the numbers for the buoyancy of a buried tank -- they might just tear their way out of the freshly saturated ground and float to the surface of the Fish Tank.

Comment: @ZeissIkon They tend not to pop to the surface during events like the Flooding of New Orleans, back in 2005 with hurricane Katrina.

Comment: @PcMan How long was it flooded, and what kind of soil was it?  Different conditions could lead to different outcomes.  Likely also depends on how full or not-full a given tank is -- air is a lot more buoyant than gasoline or diesel.

Comment: @ZeissIkon yep, hence "tend". I have actually seen a diesel tank uproot itself during flooding. But it was 90%+ empty, thus effectively an air bladder. I have also seen many tanks that just took in water, and ruined the contents. Most usually though, the tank stays where it is, and can be easily located in (still) water by the rainbow sheen on the water above it.

Comment: Don't think you'll see much "rainbow sheen" while that inch-an-hour rain is still falling -- but I can see how there'd be traces of oil/gasoline on the overflow.  Pretty small traces, relative to the flow rate, though.  Less than that from outboard motor exhaust in the outflow of a lake that allows power boats.

Comment: @PcMan 6-10 gas stations in a 2x2 mile area? As a European, that sounds absurdly high... A quick look on Google maps at say Chicago (is that a typical US suburbia?) suggests around 1 gas station in the average 2x2 mile square.

Comment: rotting organics will be heavily diluted in this huge reservoir, and you're adding 259,210 m2 of rain every hour, so after the initial flushing out of floating stuff, I think remaining contamination will be negligible.

Comment: underground storage is vented (unless gas) and water will enter the vent and displace the liquid up the vent pipe.

Comment: @DanW I took averages of gas station density for LA, San Francisco, Houston, and Denver. Excluded the city centers, excluded the agricultural regions. *included* commercial and industrial. Did a comparison of local data, to ensure accuracy of google maps vs. reality. (1 in 12 gas stations on google are nonoperational, from this check).  Europeans live near their work, and commerce. Or they use public transport. America does neither. (nor does south africa, my homegrounds)

Comment: @PcMan ok, sounds like that’s typical for some US cities - Chicago may not be typical? Probably down to the OP’s choice of setting then.

Answer (score 7):

Some math:
25mm/m2/h and about 10km2 area leads to approximately 70 m3/s of water. Not even close to large rivers, but it is a decent stream. Approx 1/100 of Danube.

Population density varies, taking a reasonably high estimate of 1k/km2: 10k people, each with 100l of problems. 5k cars, each with 100l of problems. 5k "misc" (homes and whatnot), each with 100l of problems, and you end up with 20 m3 of issues.

Now, threshold for pollution greatly depends on source. I can't be bothered to find thresholds for all sources of problems, so I took the first number I found: 50 ppm = 50 mg/l threshold (EU threshold for nitrates).

This means water is "clean" as soon as outflow of problematic stuff is below 3.5 l/s. With 20 m3, even constant linear outflow of problems (the worst case estimate) would give you mere hours to have stuff below that threshold. Even estimating 10 times as many pollutants will have the water clean enough in less than a day.

So, we can ignore suburbs. Pollution is negligible with that amount of water flow.

EDIT: we can most likely also ignore rainwater problems. With that amount of rain, it will be essentially pure water falling down. You are still going to need approximately 30 tons/day of generic pollutants to make water problematic for drinking.

(so, to make water undrinkable you need specific pollutants that have way lower threshold of causing problems. Generic post-apocalyptic pollution will not do)

Comment: I'm not sure that the captured rainwater = filtration even holds here. The rain is going to be cleaning out the air, so the particulates in the air should go to 0. The question would be if bacteria in the water can outpace the overflow, but I am thinking maybe not considering that we don't usually have bacterial problems in tap water, etc.

Comment: @user3067860 yeah, you are right. With that amount of rain you will flush all pollutants out of the air way before the day is over.

Comment: @user3067860 You hve obviously never lived in Africa or Indonesia, where tapwater and cholera can go hand-in -hand.

Comment: @ZizyArcher HOW is a 2x2 mile permanent rainstorm supposed to clear the air of an entire planet? Remember the scenario: each 2x2 mile region of earth has its own 10ft-tall enclosing walls, and its own purely local weather.

Comment: @PcMan it won't clear the air of the planet, but it doesn't have to. It will clear the air in the region where it rains. Then, to have problematic levels of pollution to make water undrinkable, you require many tons of pollutants per day entering this local rainstorm thingy. This is hard to do even deliberately.

Answer (score 4):

At the start, all the gasoline from underground tanks at filling stations, all the motor oil and similar substances from cars, all the contents of sewage treatment and septic systems, plus things like pesticides from garden stores and the like will wind up mixed into the water.  It'll be a veritable stew of coliform bacteria and chemical pollutants (not to mention all the drowned residents and their pets adding to the mix).

By the time the water is twenty or so feet deep, however, there'll be enough dilution that chemical pollutants will become nearly negligible and, as noted in another answer, boiling will be sufficient.  Assuming there's no fresh sewage or bodies going into the Fish Tank, it should be safe enough to drink without boiling in a matter of months -- the worst of the pollutants will have either washed out soon after the water starts to overflow the invisible wall, or settled to the bottom of the new "lake", leaving what's left almost completely rain water.  Given the rate of rainfall, the water inside the Fish Tank will be purer than most surface water ca. 2021 within a year (likely less).

Answer (score 2):

You would have to include what kind of and level of toxins were frequent in the suburb, account for erosion, how fast is the water churning ? How is it leaking out ? Is the water remaining muddy ? Is new sediment being introduced at all (which it sounds like it is not). What kind of air pollution may be nearby (consider acid rain), and also what kind of potentially parasite microorganisms were present to begin with that might be reproducing from preexisting waterways or soil layers that are now thriving or being introduced by some other means.

The question is kind of complex, so the answer will spark more questions.

In brief it may be that the soil pollutants will settle in a layer of silt within a month or two, but if there are harmful critters in the water, or if there were high levels of pesticides etc that were water solubale, then you may be SOL.

In the wild we tend to filter and/or treat water for a reason, there are many parasites and pollutants that make us very sick. Near springs and head waters wit natural aquifers the water is less polluted, but the idea of a crystal lake is not realistic these days and what you are describing sounds sort of like a manmade lake in an area flooded, which contained ridiculous amounts of modern pesticides herbicides gasoline, and other pollutants and trash.

There might be a breakdown of garbage and trash by natural bacteria which help things alongs and some contagions might very well die in the water, which were aerobic.

Just some thoughts.

Comment: there is basically no churn, water only escapes by overflowing. Keep in mind there is also a big difference between modern legal safety levels, and save to drink in a post apocalypses setting.

Comment: yeah but you can still be poisoned if the water is 10% raid :P I'll think a bit more.

Comment: to be 10% raid there would have to be a raid factor with a giant fluid retaining tower in the suburbs. 300,000,000 cubic meters of water is a LOT of water.

Answer (score 0):

[Water treatment plants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_purification) daily process rain water coming from the surfaces of urban area

> The goals of the treatment are to remove unwanted constituents in the water and to make it safe to drink or fit for a specific purpose in industry or medical applications. Widely varied techniques are available to remove contaminants like fine solids, micro-organisms and some dissolved inorganic and organic materials, or environmental persistent pharmaceutical pollutants. The choice of method will depend on the quality of the water being treated, the cost of the treatment process and the quality standards expected of the processed water.

The processes which are carried out are:

1. Pretreatment
2. Coagulation and flocculation
3. Sedimentation
4. Dissolved air flotation
5. Filtration
6. Removal of ions and other dissolved substances
7. Disinfection

If the water is simply kept still, only step 3 would happen naturally at a significant rate, and the growth of bacteria and algae in the water would just make the problem worse.

It would take years at best to make the water drinkable without any intervention.

Comment: But the water is being continually added to (replacing outflow) at a terrific rate -- inch-an-hour rainfall, remember?

Comment: Keep in mind this is not runoff, this is a massive amount of water put on a very small area of suburban landscape,  with no drainage, in a very short time.

Comment: Most of those are descriptions of **how** a filtering step is done, which isn't that relevant for a flood of magically induced torrential rainwater; you need a list of specific threats removed.